# Assign value of ActiveX Checkbox to Variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to assign the value of an `ActiveX` checkbox to a variable but I get the following error:

`Object does not support this property or method.`

Below is the code:

```
Dim InputSheet As Worksheet
Dim VolDiscount As Boolean
VolDiscount = InputSheet.OLEObjects("VolDiscountBox").Value
```

The name of the checkbox is `VolDiscountBox`

Is this not an OLE Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing `Object`

```
VolDiscount = InputSheet.OLEObjects("VolDiscountBox").Object.Value
```